# How do I know whether my user is from EU countries?

Tags: gdprconsentform

Since the EU is having special laws for ads publishers. I want to display the cookie consent for my users. But I just couldn't find any good frameworks on the internet to determine whether a user is from an EU country.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Hope to get some answers covering stuff in detail.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad, can you tell a bit more about how you want to achieve this? There are several ways to do this actually.

Comment: For example, I want to let the EU users load a `eu.js` script but not let the users outside EU load that script.

Comment: Maybe use a service like https://ipstack.com/ and send it the ip adress and get the country. Then you can use that info with a javascript to load eu or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you can easily do this by determining the local timezone of a user. There are several ways of doing it.

**Moment.js**

[Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) has a function that guesses the timezone of a user. It is quite accurate, provided you are using the most recent version.

Example:

```html
<div id="guess"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.getElementById('guess').innerText = moment.tz.guess();
</script>
```

Moment.js uses Intl API which is a built-in JavaScript internationalization API. It also has its data bank it checks the result of the Intl API against to provide more accurate information. It also requires you to have included Moment.js before it can work.

**Jstz package**

[Jstz](https://github.com/iansinnott/jstz) is a simple lighter package for detecting timezone. It also makes use of the Intl API, so you can be confident of its results. To use the package, you can grab the CDN as follows:

```html
<div id="guess"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.6/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.getElementById('guess').innerText = jstz.determine().name();
</script>
```

**Intl API Itself**:
You can use the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) directly!

> The Intl object is the namespace for the ECMAScript Internationalization API, which provides language sensitive string comparison, number formatting, and date and time formatting. The Intl object provides access to several constructors as well as functionality common to the internationalization constructors and other language sensitive functions.

Example usage:

```html
<div id="guess"></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('guess').innerText = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
</script>
```

What you can notice from these libraries used for detecting timezone is that they do not require any network calls from your end. This means if you intend to only pick user timezones, you may not need to do IP lookups.

Then you can just match the timezone with the specific EU timezone and determine if your user is from within EU.

If you want to do an actual/accurate pinpointing of a user, you have to use GeoLocation. Here is a simple script which does that: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdeyinkaAdegbenro/Detect_Location/master/detect_location.js.

Other APIs you might want to check (whatever suits you):

- http://ip-api.com/json
- https://ipinfo.io/
- https://geoip-db.com

Comment: Since the timezones extend longitudinally, isn't this going to give false positives for folks in Africa? For example, Spain and South Africa are in the same time zone. Is the library sophisticated enough to distinguish between the two?

Comment: @Mattia please do your research my friend. The answer was posted like 2 years ago, if you find inconsistencies somewhere feel free to update the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the accepted answer, I did all the hard work in determining which time zones are subject to the GDPR laws. I used the [`dayjs`](https://day.js.org/en/) package, which is similar to [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

```js
const EU_TIMEZONES = [
  'Europe/Vienna',
  'Europe/Brussels',
  'Europe/Sofia',
  'Europe/Zagreb',
  'Asia/Famagusta',
  'Asia/Nicosia',
  'Europe/Prague',
  'Europe/Copenhagen',
  'Europe/Tallinn',
  'Europe/Helsinki',
  'Europe/Paris',
  'Europe/Berlin',
  'Europe/Busingen',
  'Europe/Athens',
  'Europe/Budapest',
  'Europe/Dublin',
  'Europe/Rome',
  'Europe/Riga',
  'Europe/Vilnius',
  'Europe/Luxembourg',
  'Europe/Malta',
  'Europe/Amsterdam',
  'Europe/Warsaw',
  'Atlantic/Azores',
  'Atlantic/Madeira',
  'Europe/Lisbon',
  'Europe/Bucharest',
  'Europe/Bratislava',
  'Europe/Ljubljana',
  'Africa/Ceuta',
  'Atlantic/Canary',
  'Europe/Madrid',
  'Europe/Stockholm'
];

const isConsentRequired = () => {
  dayjs.extend(timezone);
  return EU_TIMEZONES.includes(dayjs.tz.guess());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on `@Andrew Samole` answer but works with vanilla js:

```
function determineIfCookieConsentRequired() {
    const EU_TIMEZONES = [
        'Europe/Vienna',
        'Europe/Brussels',
        'Europe/Sofia',
        'Europe/Zagreb',
        'Asia/Famagusta',
        'Asia/Nicosia',
        'Europe/Prague',
        'Europe/Copenhagen',
        'Europe/Tallinn',
        'Europe/Helsinki',
        'Europe/Paris',
        'Europe/Berlin',
        'Europe/Busingen',
        'Europe/Athens',
        'Europe/Budapest',
        'Europe/Dublin',
        'Europe/Rome',
        'Europe/Riga',
        'Europe/Vilnius',
        'Europe/Luxembourg',
        'Europe/Malta',
        'Europe/Amsterdam',
        'Europe/Warsaw',
        'Atlantic/Azores',
        'Atlantic/Madeira',
        'Europe/Lisbon',
        'Europe/Bucharest',
        'Europe/Bratislava',
        'Europe/Ljubljana',
        'Africa/Ceuta',
        'Atlantic/Canary',
        'Europe/Madrid',
        'Europe/Stockholm'
      ];

    var dayjs_script = document.createElement('script');
    var dayjs_tz_script = document.createElement('script');

    dayjs_script.onload = function(e) {
        document.head.appendChild(dayjs_tz_script);
    }
    dayjs_tz_script.onload = function () {
        dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_timezone);
        var tz = dayjs.tz.guess();
        if(EU_TIMEZONES.includes(tz)) {
            checkIfAcceptedCookies();
        } else {
            onAcceptedCookies();
        }
    };
    dayjs_script.onerror = function() {
        checkIfAcceptedCookies();
    }
    dayjs_tz_script.onerror = function() {
        checkIfAcceptedCookies();
    }

    dayjs_tz_script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.6/plugin/timezone.min.js';
    dayjs_script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.6/dayjs.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(dayjs_script);
}
```

Simply run `determineIfCookieConsentRequired()` to check if consent is required.

You then need to create two functions:

- `checkIfAcceptedCookies()` which should check if the user has already consented or display a banner asking them to
- `onAcceptedCookies()` to do whatever you want once cookies are consented (or if they're not required)

Answer (score -1):

### Steps to check if user is living in Europe/EU:

1. Obtain the object from the `resolvedOptions` function from the `DateTimeFormat` function from the `Intl` object
2. Set `isInEu` to a boolean if the `timeZone` property contains `Europe`

```js
isInEu = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone.indexOf("Europe") == 0
```

---

> Yep, it's *that* simple! - Leonardo Da Tyrunt

---

Comment: Many countries in Europe are not members of the EU. Some systems in Europe will be operating in a different time zone, and correspondingly, some systems outside of Europe will be using one in Europe.